# How to start the grid with a space?? CSS

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yU8U.png)i have a problem with a web design. I need to copy a homepage from invision and the thing it's that the grid of the design start with a space like its have a padding but it dosen't. I'd appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: put content: " ", where?

Comment: Is there any code involved you want to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add space in css grid by using `gap` property.

see [CSS grid gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap)

Comment: Yes, i do that but i need agree and initial and end space

Comment: @Martin Leonardo Arias Paz in css most scenario to add a space to the element is by using padding, margin or gap